# Flask downloads previous file version in response

Tags: python, flask, download, request

I'm running a flask application that downloads a zip file that the user created.

The zipfile is deleted/overwritten with the same name for the user in the directory.

Then, when I get the download link, it downloads the old zipfile with the deleted files that cant be opened.

The link works correctly on incognito mode.

However in regular chrome, the request doesn't hit the test server before serving the zip file.

Anyone know what the issue might be?

```
@page.route('/response/<id>')
def response(id):
    user = User.query.filter(User.spreadsheet_id.any(id)).first()
    print(user.spreadsheet_id)
    zip_name = f'{user.email}_zip.zip'
    path = ''
    root_dir = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
    print(os.path.join(root_dir, 'app', zip_name))
    return send_file(os.path.join(root_dir, 'app', zip_name),  mimetype='zip', attachment_filename=zip_name, as_attachment=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case the solution was to wrap the attachment in a `Response` object and add a cache-control header:

```
attachment = send_file(os.path.join(root_dir, 'app', zip_name),  mimetype='zip', attachment_filename=zip_name, as_attachment=True)
resp = make_response(attachment)
resp.cache_control.max_age = 120
return resp
```